# Events emitted from ASP.NET core service created as part of Service Fabric app don't show up in Diagnostic Event Viewer

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Working with the Service Fabric, Diagnostic Events Viewer in Visual Studio plays a huge role as it allows me to see all the messages posted from my fabric services. When I add another service to the app, it always gets created with its own instance of EventSource class that I can use to emit messages. But when it comes to a service created as ASP.NET core project, I don't see any of the events. I don't even see ETW Provider from the ASP.NET core project on the list of all the registered providers in Diagnostic Events Viewer. Any thoughts on how to make events logged from the ASP.NET Core project present in the Viewer?

P.S.

I was able to see events emitted from ASP.NET Core project with PerfView utility, but it's not as much comfortable as Diagnostic Events Viewer.

Comment: Did you make any alterations to the provided event source code?

Comment: Nope, I did not.

Comment: What happens of you manually add the id of the ETW provider to the list in the Diagnostic Events Viewer?

Comment: It actually starts showing the events if I add the provider. Somehow that part of being able to add a provider in that window slipped away from me. Awesome! Thank you! Any clue on why it doesn't appear automatically when it comes to .net core service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on the conversation with Peter Bons, the issue could be 'solved' by adding provider name manually into the list of all the registered providers in Diagnostic Event Viewer, and then events start showing. Although why it does not happen automatically for Asp.Net Core Service remains TBD.